# Typescript type lost after spreading

Tags: typescript

Probably I am missing something obvious here but why does this not work ?

`this.props.entity` is most definitely of type GraphData and the attribute in delta is valid on GraphData.

```
    const newEntity: GraphData = {...this.props.entity, ...delta } as GraphData;
    if(newEntity instanceof GraphData) {
        console.log('Yay');
    }
```

even this does not work

```
    const newEntity: GraphData = {...this.props.entity } as GraphData;
    if(newEntity instanceof GraphData) {
        console.log('Yay');
    }
```

newEntity is always of type Object

Comment: `newEntity` will never be an instance of anything other than Object since you're not using constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript has a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). This means if you define `class A { x: number = 1; }`, then the object literal `{x: 1}` is of type `A` even though it wasn't constructed like `new A()`.

However, `instanceof` is Javascript, so it has the same semantics in Typescript [as it has in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether the `prototype` property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object.

So since the object literal `{x: 1}` doesn't have `A.prototype` in its prototype chain, `{x: 1} instanceof A` is false. That is, `instanceof` is **not** testing whether the object has a particular type in Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an instance of the `GraphData` class, then you have to use the `new` operator:

```
const newEntity = new GraphData(/* ... */);
```

Or, you can declare `GraphData` as an `interface` or a `type` but then you won't be able to use `instanceof` at runtime.